# prestashop - Display status of order in AdminStats

Tags: prestashop, admin, status

I want the status order to display at AdminStats. I created the file override/controllers/admin/AdminStatsController.php:

```
<?php // Check order status in Stats Dashboard BO class AdminStatsController extends AdminStatsControllerCore {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->fields_list['order_statuses'] = array('title' => $this->l('Order Status');            
    }
}
```

But when I go to AdminStats, a blank page shows up (see image below).

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I can’t identify those statistics, what is it? How do I find it?

Comment: Hello,

After products were sold (shipped or accepted), you can see product of sale.

Comment: Still without find it, could you be more clear indicating the path, ie. `PS17 > BO > Stats > Etc > Etc`. Because I don’t even know what version of PrestaShop you have.

Comment: Hello,

I'm using Prestashop 1.6.1.18
/adminxxx/index.php?controller=AdminStats&token=057xxx&module=statsproduct&id_product=2

Comment: I have checked my PS 1.6 in the `BO > Stats > Product details > (clicked some product)` and definitely I can't see the screen like your screenshot, I'm sorry.

Comment: The product was sold and was shipped, It will appear like my screen.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: this is not the solution in respect to the question asked.**

I'd to do the exact same thing. I did it something like this, but it was `AdminOrdersController` but it's pretty much the same. Here it is,

```
// override/controllers/admin/AdminStatsController.php
<?php
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->fields_list = array_merge($this->fields_list, [
       'order_statuses' => [
            'title' => $this->l('Order Status'),
            'align' => 'text-center',
            'callback' => 'orderStatusFunction', // yes, a callback to get a piece of UI back, a button maybe
            'orderby' => false, // or true, anything you'd like
            'search' => false,
            'remove_onclick' => true,
       ]
    ]);
  }
}
```

Now the callback

```
<?php
public function orderStatusFunction($row_number, $row_data) // row_data like date, order, customer, etc
{
    /* do stuff with data and assign to your template */
    $view = _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'path/to/view/file/view.tpl';
    $html = $this->context->smarty->createTemplate($view, $this->context->smarty)->fetch();
    return $html;
}
```

Let me know if you've any confusion, or if it didn't work out.

Comment: Hello,

I tried to do your code but it fails :(
Blank page disappear but the code didn't work.

Comment: the information you posted earlier was not updated, hence this isn't the solution for you. you've to understand and modify this module called `statsproduct` which I definitely wouldn't recommend. If you're not likely to update then this could work for you

Comment: I would recommend you to create a module just like `statsproduct` and work your way around and not modify `statsproduct`

Comment: if you take a look at `statsproduct.php` class method `hookAdminStatsModules` you would find the html registering as panel item `Product Details`. this hook is your target

Comment: copy and paste the content of `statsproduct.php` to your new module and modify any way you'd want to. Once done, disable `statsproduct` module and enable yours

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response. I'm really php beginner (I learn myself on internet) so I can not understand such as: $row_number, $row_data. Can you write full module code for this case?

Comment: are you a developer yourself or you just need to get this done?? I suspect the former. I'd really recommend you put some work into it yourself. this way you'll learn a lot. if you can't I'm sorry but you need to hire somebody to do it..